# How to divide beamer into different parts?

Tags: beamer, subfloats, minipage

[image]

I want to divide the beamer into A, B, C, three parts, and A is divided into a and b.

I tried

```
\minipage{0.3\linewidth} %for A
\minipage{0.5\linewidth} %for a
\minipage{0.5\linewidth} %for b

\minipage{0.3\linewidth} %for B

\minipage{0.3\linewidth} %for C
```

while it doesn't work.

I also tried `\minipage` with `\subfloat`, but the error message with subfloat outside float.

So how to divide the beamer page properly?

Comment: So, you want a 2x3 `tabular` with two` \multirow` cells. Using true minipages environments (and not the pseudocode that you showed) it is also possible, but  with  "a" and "b" *nested in*  "A" (not *next to* "A") and both ("a" and "b") with a width of `\linewidth`  (i.e., the  full width of "A", not of the frame).  Or using   `columns`, but note that whatever the solution, if "a" and "b" boxes are frameless and of equal width, they are completely superfluous and can be replaced, if needed, with some vertical space as `\vfill` between the top and bottom content of "A".

Answer (score 1):

Try the `columns` environment from `beamer`.

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand\dummy{Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{columns}[t]
    \begin{column}{.333\textwidth}
      \begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \dummy
      \end{minipage}\par
      \begin{minipage}[t][.5\textheight]{\textwidth}
        \dummy
      \end{minipage}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.333\textwidth}
      \dummy
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.333\textwidth}
      \dummy
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works!